# jquery not working correctly on onchange event attribute of html

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am using jquery to get the data from mysql when dropdown is selected. but it runs perfectly on my local environment but loads previous data on server even if the data is not exist in mysql.

```
<select name="book_no" id="name" class="form-control selectpicker" data-index="2" data-live-search="true"  onchange="$('#amount').load('ajax.php?NAME=' + $('#name :selected').val());$('#output1').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));$('#book_series').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('ids'))">
```

and this is the code which is in ajax.php file

```
<?php
  include 'include/db.php';
  $NAME = $_REQUEST['NAME'];

  ?>
   <script>
   console.log("Hello");
   </script>

                      <label>Slip Start</label>
                      <?php
          $query = "Select * from book_slip where book_code = '$NAME'" ;
          $res = mysqli_query($con , $query);

          ?>
          <select name="ss" id="names" class="form-control" onchange="$('#amoun').load('ajax1.php?NAME=' + $('#names :selected').val());">
          <option value=""></option>

          <?php
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
          echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[book_slip]</option>";

       }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
```

the main purpose of this code is to get slips values which is not used until now if slip is used it will be deleted from database. and when i check in database slip is not shown but it is showing in my form what should i do.

Comment: " loads previous data on server even if the data is not exist in mysql." Could be a caching issue in your browser, or on the webserver? Also check that the copy of the application installed on your server is in fact querying the correct database. P.S. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Learn to use parameterised queries and prepared statements to better protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for more info and examples of how to write queries correctly in PHP/mysqli syntax

Comment: Probably a simple cache issue. Add a cachebuster parameter (like the current timestamp) to your request. Btw., you should really use jQuery’s event handling here, instead of stuffing all that code into an HTML attribute.

Comment: its a cache issue but how can i remove that issue

Comment: Thanks CBroe and ADyson for your response

Comment: Add '&cache='+Math.random() to the ajax url

Comment: Thank You  Manuel Otto it works